# Remove a nested item from an array based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem that seems easy to resolve, but I tried for hours with no success. I want to remove an item on a specific list's id and a specific content's id.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "First list",
    content: [
      { id: 10, name: "item1" },
      { id: 11, name: "item2" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Second list",
    content: [
      { id: 12, name: "item1" },
      { id: 1, name: "item3" },
    ],
  },
];
```

I try with `.filter()` and `.map()` but can't get it working as expected.

expected output:

```js
const filter = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "First list",
    content: [{ id: 10, name: "item1" }],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Second list",
    content: [
      { id: 12, name: "item1" },
      { id: 13, name: "item3" },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: do you need the new array or should i fix the current array

Comment: i need to obtain the new array

Comment: that takes a lot of memory are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: yep , i want to remove an element from a redux state

Comment: What have you tried already on your own? What is the code that isn't working? We can't address issues with code we can't see. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that keeps the original item reference when possible, and only includes a new item object when it is the one that needs to have a content item removed:

```js
const removeItem = (data, id, contentId) => 
    data.map(item => item.id != id ? item : {
        ...item,
        content: item.content.filter(({id}) => id != contentId)
    });

// Demo
const data = [{id: 1,name: "First list",content: [{ id: 10, name: "item1" },{ id: 11, name: "item2" },],},{id: 2,name: "Second list",content: [{ id: 12, name: "item1" },{ id: 1, name: "item3" },],},];
const filter = removeItem(data, 1, 11);
console.log(filter);
```

Comment: Thx a lot ! i used your solution.

Answer (score 0):

try code:

```js
  const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "First list",
      content: [
        { id: 10, name: "item1" },
        { id: 11, name: "item2" },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Second list",
      content: [
        { id: 12, name: "item1" },
        { id: 1, name: "item3" },
      ],
    },
  ];
  
  const filter = data.map(item => {
  // if you need remove 1 item
  const newContent = item.content.slice(0)
  newContent.splice(newContent.findIndex(item => item.id === 11) >>> 0, 1)

  // if you need to delete with specific condition
  // const newContent = item.content.filter(item => item.id !== 11)
  return {
    ...item,
    content: newContent
  }
})

console.log(filter)
```

> Note: this is according to your request, i create a completely new array and actual object, we don't need to do this because it takes memory

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `listId` and `contentId` are the specific ids that you want to remove:

```
const newList = data.map((list) => {
  if (list.id === listId) {
    const newContent = list.content.filter((item) => item.id !== contentId);
    return { ...list, content: newContent };
  }
  return list;
});
```